# Number of records in 32 kilobytes?

Tags: byte, storage, arduino, eeprom

I am considering buying an external [EEPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM) storage module for my microcontroller. However, it only has 32 kilobytes storage capacity.

I'm using this to store records where each record is basically 4 separate numbers ranging between 0 - 180.

How many records do you think 32 kilobytes could handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single record is an element out of a range of `181^4` possible elements, giving an information entropy of `log(181^4)/log(2) = 29.999 bits`. So you can, with some effort, encode one element in 30 bits.

This means you have `floor(32 * 1024 * 8 / 30) = 8738` elements you can store. If you choose to encode using 32 bits - 4 bytes - for a significant simplification in your encoding logic, then it's `32 * 1024 * 8 / 32 = 8192` elements.

This analysis does not count any additional overhead for metadata such as validity bits, or flags to indicate which element is the newest, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you can store 8k elements using 4 bytes for each record in the EEPROM, have you considered using an [SD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) card instead of an EEPROM? There are quite cheap SD card [shields](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) available for the Arduino, and, in addition, SD cards are very cheap and you won't have any space problems. You can access the SD card by [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus).

Comment: I actually tried the SD method but the problem is it's basically only good for storing log files. With the eeprom method I can quickly find any record stored by simply calling the address number. Whereas with a log file I have to loop through the file to get to the line number. The other downfall with sd is arduino can't delete lines or overwrite in a text file (at least I couldn't find any info on it).

Comment: Can't you have files of records on SD-cards?